# Python3 String Manipulation Using Replacement

Tags: python-3.x, string

I want to create a list of vowels from a string that contains letters and still have the consonants in that string. I have something that worked for a particular string, with one occurrence in that string but when I have multiple occurrences, it does not work.

PRINCELY worked well,
EMEKA did not work.

I need help!

```
alphabets = {"A":1,"B":2,"C":3, "D":4,"E":5,"F":6,"G":7,"H":8,"I":9,"J":1,"K":2,"L":3,"M":4,"N":5,"O":6,"P":7,"Q":8,"R":9,"S":1,
         "T":2,"U":3,"V":4,"W":5, "X":6,"Y":7,"Z":8}

def digit_sum(num):
    return sum( [ int(char) for char in str(num) ] )

def numerology(word):
    total = 0
    for letter in word:
            total += alphabets[letter]
            total = digit_sum(total)

    return total

fan = 'PRINCELY'

def vowels(fan):
    vowels=[]
    if 'I' in fan:
        vowels.append(9)
        fan1=fan[:fan.index('I')]+fan[fan.index('I')+1:]
        consonant = fan1
        if 'E' in fan:
            vowels.append(5)
            fan2=fan1[:fan1.index('E')]+fan1[fan1.index('E')+1:]
            consonant = fan2
            if 'A' in fan:
                vowels.append(1)
                fan3=fan2[:fan2.index('A')]+fan2[fan2.index('A')+1:]
                consonant = fan3
                if 'O' in fan:
                    vowels.append(6)
                    fan4=fan3[:fan3.index('O')]+fan3[fan3.index('O')+1:]
                    consonant = fan4
                    if 'U' in fan:
                        vowels.append(3)
                        fan5=fan4[:fan4.index('U')]+fan4[fan4.index('U')+1:]
                        consonant = fan5
    print(vowels)
    print(consonant)
    print(digit_sum(sum(vowels)))
    cons = numerology(consonant)
    print(cons)

vowels(fan)

#outputs
#[9, 5]
#PRNCLY
#5
#7
```

Comment: This isn't a [MCVE]. It's unclear why you'd do this rather than use `str.replace` (obvious) or `str.translate` (more involved, but more efficient). Is this homework? Are you prevented from using reasonable solutions for some reason? Why are you making `vowels` separate from `fan1`/`fan2`/`consonant` (thereby forgetting where the vowels were)? Why use `if` conditions instead of `while` to get them all?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `str.translate` with an appropriate translation table.  First we'll make a function that takes a character and returns the appropriate number as a string.  We'll use that to build a translation table.  Then we just use that translation table on the string

```
def get_number(char):
    return str(ord(char.lower())-96)  # lowercase ascii letters start at 97

vowels = (vowel for letter in 'aeiou' for vowel in (letter, letter.upper()))

table = str.maketrans({vowel: get_number(vowel) for vowel in vowels})

print('PRINCELYPRINCELY'.translate(table))
# PR9NC5LYPR9NC5LY
```

To sort the string into vowels and consonants, and then turn the vowels into numbers you could do

```
s = 'PRINCELYPRINCELY'

vowels = [ord(char.lower())-96 for char in s if char.lower() in 'aeiou']
# [9, 5, 9, 5]
consonants = s.translate(str.maketrans('','','aeiouAEIOU'))
# 'PRNCLYPRNCLY'
```

Comment: The vowels are highly needed, in fact, the vowels are very important here, and they need to be in vowels list, and be deleted in fan because I need the consonants seperate

Comment: Thanks, @PatrickHaugh, your code gave me a more simple idea. But how do I sort the output to something like: vowels = [9,5,9,5] , so that I can get the sum, and consonants = 'PRNCLYPRNCLY' because I need to convert it to numbers and get the sum too. Please help me.